# This is regarding adding constraints in sql

Tags: mysql, constraints, primary-key

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT(
ROLL_NO INT NOT NULL,
STU_NAME VARCHAR (35) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
STU_AGE INT NOT NULL,
STU_ADDRESS VARCHAR (35) UNIQUE,
CONSTRAINT PK_Student PRIMARY KEY (ROLL_NO)
);
```

Here I can't understand what is PK_Student in ADD CONSTRAINT?? What is the purpose of writing that??

Comment: I wouldn't consider a PK to be a CONSTRAINT, although I suppose technically it can be understood that way.

Comment: @Strawberry, Yes, a PK is a constraint. For example, it appears in the TABLE_CONSTRAINTS metadata table.

Answer (score 0):

> what is PK_Student in ADD CONSTRAINT??

Each constraint must have a name (more precise a "symbol"). This symbol must be unique in the whole database over this constraint type (primary key, unique index, foreign key, check).

So this is an attempt to assign a name to the primary key constraint.

A pointless and unsuccessful attempt !

Primary key constraint have no name (or it is not shown in `SHOW CREATE TABLE`), but for a reference to it PK constraint have static, reserved and unchanged alias `PRIMARY` (i.e. only primary key constraint or primary key index with the name `PRIMARY` can be created). Or the primary key always have the name `PRIMARY`, but it is not shown in `SHOW CREATE TABLE` - it is the same.

So the name `PK_Student` will be simply ignored. You can see this in the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c58b71c3af5c0f2d91d564bf3c456886).

---

And again in another words:

1. Constraint symbol or index name for Primary Key other than `PRIMARY` will be ignored;
2. Assigning the symbol/name `PRIMARY` to constraint or index other than Primary Key will fail.

Comment: While the constraint name `PK_Student` is ignored for primary key constraints, it is stored for other constraint types. [db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1a1dacfc0be59338b77361263ac5eba2;)

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica I have said nothing about names of constraints/indices other than PK one. I have said only: 1) Constraint name or index name for PK other than `PRIMARY` will be ignored 2) Assigning the name `PRIMARY` to constraint or index other than PK will fail.

Comment: I was just pointing this out for the benefit of anyone who reads your answer and didn't already know this.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL in particular, the constraint name for a PRIMARY KEY is ignored. I tested creating your example table in my `test` schema, and then I examined the metadata:

```
mysql> select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS where constraint_schema='test';
+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+
| CONSTRAINT_CATALOG | CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA | CONSTRAINT_NAME | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | CONSTRAINT_TYPE |
+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+
| def                | test              | PRIMARY         | test         | STUDENT    | PRIMARY KEY     |
| def                | test              | STU_NAME        | test         | STUDENT    | UNIQUE          |
| def                | test              | STU_ADDRESS     | test         | STUDENT    | UNIQUE          |
+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+
```

You can see the PRIMARY KEY constraint is simply named "PRIMARY", disregarding the constraint name in your CREATE TABLE statement.

Naming the constraint is valid SQL syntax, but MySQL silently ignores it in this case.

In some other brands of SQL database, like Oracle or Microsoft, the constraint name would be remembered.

Constraints have names so you can examine them in metadata, or in some cases you can drop them by specifying the name.